# Generate random pairs of factors in dataframe using R

Tags: r, random, combn

I have a character vector data frame and I would like to randomly generate pairs of names coming from this vector. My code gives the all combinations. But I want to generate all names should be paired with one time in random order; an item cannot be partner with itself.
My code is:

```
# Creating a dataframe
df = data.frame(
  "Name" = c("Amiya", "Raj", "Asish", "John", "ruban", "mary", "barath", "leema", "joshi", "indhu", "praveen", "joshua",
             "alex", "martin", "stella", "veronica", "henry", "rajesh", "yusuf", "jenita", "johana", "jerald", "jegan", "lincy",
             "jona", "rani", "julie", "ross", "chandler", "monica", "penny", "sheldon"),
  
  "Sex" = c("Female", "Male", "Male", "male", "male", "Female", "male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "male",
            "male", "male", "male", "Female", "Female", "male", "male", "male", "Female", "Female", "male",
            "male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "male", "male", "Female", "Female", "male"),
  
  "Number" = c(8937998889, 2598279874, 4589987483, 2876876877, 2876876876, 2487698798, 2879879877, 2887987897, 2878798733,
               4309808098, 8748098990, 9883798798, 8734787987, 8973498787, 8734887877, 9798374877, 8786487687, 7275687263,
               4379879847, 8943787876, 3874879874, 8978973987, 8978347878, 8839478768, 9378887774, 8467676764, 7246276874,
               7478798743, 6576787877, 7328776876, 6648678833, 6378787878)
)
print(df)

# Accessing first and second column
cat("Accessing first and second column\n")
dat <- print(df[, 1])

t(combn(unique(dat,2)))
```

TIA

Comment: I guess your `)` is at different position i.e. `t( combn(unique(dat), 2))`

Comment: Do you want `t(combn(sample(unique(df$Name)), 2))`

Comment: @akrun Yes, but each names should be paired with only one time

Comment: `combn` does that.

Comment: @akrun but t(combn(sample(unique(df$Name)), 2))  paired with many times, All names should be paired with only one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `unique` elements from 'Name' column, `sample` it and convert to a `matrix` with 2 columns (assuming the length of unique elements are even)

```
matrix(sample(unique(df$Name)), ncol = 2)
```